# Is there any way to make these link inside another link work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<a class="list-group-item hola" id="competition-card-<%= competition.id %>" href="a_url_to_a_site">
    <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-xs-11'>
            Some text
          </div>

        <div class='col-xs-1 shows-submenu'>
           Some text
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

I'm trying to achieve:

1. If user clicks the 'a' tag he is directed to a site, except when...
2. user clicks the '.shows-submenu' div a hidden div is displayed.

My jQuery is as follows:

```
$('body').on('click', '.shows-submenu', function(e) {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  if ($(this).closest('a.list-group-item').next('.hidden-group-item').hasClass('hide')) {
     $('.hidden-group-item').addClass('hide');
     $(this).closest('a.list-group-item').next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');
  }
  else {
     $(this).closest('a.list-group-item').next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');
  }
});
```

Currently, if I click '.shows-submenu' div the 'a' tag is still called and I'm directed to the site.
As I'm using bootcards plugin I can't change the 'a' tag to a div, for example.

Is there any way to stop 'a' only when clicking the '.shows-submenu' div. I've tried using stopPropagation in both 'a' and the 'div' without success.

Comment: Why would you use this markup structure in the first place? Using semantic markup would make more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).  Both `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` will affect other event handlers but not the default behavior of an anchor.   Also you should declare the argument as `event` if that's how you're referring to it inside the function:

```js
$('.show-submenu').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com">this follows link
    <div class="show-submenu">this does not</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `event.stopPropagation()` that will prevent bubbling and `event.preventDefault` that will avoid the default behavior for links onClick.

Fortunately, in jQuery returning false inside the click handler function will fire both. More on the subject here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/670377

So you just need to modify your function as:

```
$('document').on('click', '.shows-submenu', function(e) {
  if ($(this).closest('a.list-group-item').next('.hidden-group-item').hasClass('hide')) {
     $('.hidden-group-item').addClass('hide');
     $(this).closest('a.list-group-item').next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');
  }
  else {
     $(this).closest('a.list-group-item').next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');
  }
  // This will be equivalent to 
  // e.preventDefault; e.stopPropagation;
  return false;
});
```

[event.stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) has another purpose than just stopping the default functionality, it will also prevent all the remaining listeners of the element from being called.

Comment: first statement is not true, a quick google search will prove it false

Comment: oh, you are right @charlietfl! edited. I have to stop assuming things :/

Comment: @TomSarduy thanks for your answer Tom it works well. I'm accepting Billy's answer as he answered before but giving you points for your help!